# Can I play Bad Company 2 with Intel dual-core 2.8 GHz

Tags: battlefield-bad-company-2

Can I play Bad Company 2 with the following hardware?

- Intel dual-core 2.8 GHz CPU
- 2GB RAM
- 512MB external graphics card
- Windows XP, service pack 2

Comment: you're borderline. To give you a yes or no answer, we'd have to know what video card you have, not just how much ram it has. Just because you meet the min specs does not mean it will be playable for multiplayer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about system requirements.

Comment: why don't you just try it? I understand when people ask questions that are somewhat difficult to find out yourself, but such a question is just... TRY IT YOURSELF! Install and run! You probably spent more time waiting for the answer than you would spend installing and trying

Answer (score 2):

Your system is capable of running the game. Check out the minimum and recommended system requirements for Battlefield: Bad Company 2.

**Minimum System Requirements:**
OS: Windows XP
Processor: Core 2 DUO @ 2 GHz
Memory: 2 GB
Hard Drive: 15 GB for Digital Version, 10 GB for Disc Version
Video Memory: 256 MB (NVIDIA GeForce 7800GT/ATI X1900)
Sound Card: DirectX Compatible
DirectX: 9.0c

**Recommended System Requirements:**
OS: Windows Vista/7
Processor: Any Quadcore Processor
Memory: 2 GB
Hard Drive: 15 GB for Digital Version, 10 GB for Disc Version
Video Memory: 512 MB (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 260)
Sound Card: DirectX Compatible
DirectX: 10

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, but it'll be slow.
You can get a  good increase in frames by OCing your processor into the 3+Ghz range.
Unless of course your GPU isn't powerful enough and bottlenecks your CPU. More information about your graphics would be helpful. A model number would tell us a lot more about it's capabilities.